# Cómo puedo reemplazar varios caracteres con String.Replace?

Tags: c#, .net, str-replace

Necesito reemplazar varios carácteres con el método `Replace()`, pero no logro que funcione de una manera correcta.

```
Text.Replace("-","");
```

y quiero tambien que reemplace las barras (`/`)

```
Text.Replace("/","");
```

Necesito hacer todo en una misma línea, que reemplace ambas cosas a la vez.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/es/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) te devuelve un string, tranquilamente podes hacer los dos en una línea.

```
Text.Replace("-","").Replace("/","");
```

Comment: Si! es lo que hice! No me funcionaba pero se ve que tenia algun parentesis mal puesto. Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
String text = Text.Replace("-", "").Replace("/", "");
```

Si necesitas cambiar la referencia `Text` directamente entonces debes hacer:

```
Text = Text.Replace("-", "").Replace("/", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perdona no me fije en el lenguaje, eso es por que esa función te pide CHARS lo cual se establece con comillas simples, prueba a poner-lo así:

string Texto = "Probando-El/TextoCon-Varios/Caracteres";
string Retorno = Texto.Replace('-', ' ');
Texto = Retorno;
Retorno = Texto.Replace('/', ' ');
MessageBox.Show(Retorno);

Comment: Amigo, creo que Maria Eugenia buscaba la respuesta en C#, tu código al parecer es javascript.